# Does dying in the Colosseum prevent the 'Undefeated' trophy from being earned?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

The text of the trophy is as follows:

> Clear the game without using the "Continue" option

Now, when you die in the Colosseum, you don't actually see the continue/load screen, so can you die as many times as you want in the Colosseum without worrying about losing the ability to earn this trophy, or does it count as a "continue" in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Dying in the Colosseum does not prevent you from obtaining the trophy. In my run, I lost during two of the cups, and still got the trophy at the end. It seems that you will only not get the trophy using the "Continue" option from the death screen.